# Monitor when a new resource is created in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to find a way to notify me when a **new** resource is being created in azure. specifically the time stamp of creation and resource id.

1. One approach was to check the system topic azure offer but it resulted in an event that basically happens after the resource is created and is more operational.
2. Another approach is to monitor the activity log or maybe event export to log analytics and check there for information.
3. if nothing will work I'll create a policy that requires users/terraform to create tagging of (created time) when provisioning resources

another requirement is to detect changes on an **existing** resource specifically on changes being made on diagnostic settings targets or metrics.

do you have any idea how to get these information?
I'm moving in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on Event Grid for that. Your Azure Function will consume the event from Event Grid, which contains a property "eventTime" and this is the timestamp you're looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema

Comment: thanks, but I mainly ask which events I need to check and get the "eventTime" from?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation and I solved with Event Grid System Topics at a subscription level . Once the system topic is setup it tracks all resource events across the resource-groups within the subscription . So only one system topic at a subscription level made it simple for me.

The diagram below explains my setup . I setup a dedicated subscription with the service bus queue to centrally store all resource related events . But it can be even in one of the other subscriptions .

[image]